# Получение информации из поля ввода

Tags: php, javascript

Есть input, в него ввожу первые две буквы, выскакивает список городов (аля google поиск). Это все дело формируется в табличку. Нужно кликнуть по городу в табличке и это значение должно перейти в input. Как я только не извращался и сколько перечитал уже на форумах, башка лопнет скоро... может  кто сталкивался?

Answer (score 3):

Если устроит на jQuery, то [смотрим работу скрипта](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/Rcg5u/)

**HTML**

```
<input id="field" type="text" name="somename" value="" />
<ul id="town_list">
        <li>Москва</li>
        <li>Верхние Петушки</li>
        <li>Задолбалово</li>
        <li>Малые Бухари</li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#town_list li').click(function(){
    var curTown = $(this).text();
    $('#field').val(curTown);
});
```

Comment: Выбор названий отличный :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
fucntion insert_value(text){
var input = document.getElementById('inputik');
input.value = text;
}
</script>
<input type="text" id="inputik" />

<button onClick="insert_value('Какое-то значение, это значение можно генерировать вашим запросом');"></button>
```

Comment: Я вот так пытаюсь

    tblRow = document.createElement("tr");
    tblCell = document.createElement("td");
    // задаем атрибуты и функции ячеек
    tblCell.onclick = function () {
        document.forms['form1'].city.value = this.prototype;
    };

Comment: кстати чего у меня код нормально не печатует вы ж тут глаза поламаете пока прочтете??)